# How to align polygons horizontally in inkscape?

Tags: inkscape

how do I align the octagon horizontally so the top line is horizontal.

[image]

Comment: First choice- draw it horizontally. Second choice- make a horizontal guide and snap your octagon to that. I use Illustrator and not Inkscape so I cannot give you a step by step, but these are fairly easy maneuvers in any vector program.

Answer (score 4):

Seemingly you have noticed that drawing an octagon by holding Ctrl at the same time doesn't give the right orientation. You get one corner right upwards, but the snapping angles do not contain the one which makes one side horizontal.

One workaround is to hold down <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> while you draw an octagon. This will snap the rotation angle to 15 degree increments so that you can create it with the corner pointing straight up, or straight down. Then apply *Object > Transform*, select the *Rotate* tab and input the angle as `360/2/8`. Then hit Apply.

If the drawn (regular) polygon has odd number of corners (3,5,7,...) and it's drawn one corner right upwards, flipping the polygon turns the already horizontal bottom side up.

Another trick is to drag down from the ruler a horizontal guide:

[image]

If you have snap to guides and snap to node ON it snaps to the uppermost corner.

Move the rotation center (click to get into rotation mode) to the corner on the guide. To make it snap you must also have snap to rotation center ON (see NOTE1). Rotate the octagon so that the top edge snaps to the guide:

[image]

NOTE1: I have found it's useful to keep all snap to points, to centers and to guides ON, but to keep snap to grid and snap to bounding box OFF. I change it only when needed.

Comment: Hope you don't mind, but I made a little edit to your first workaround, just to make it clear the polygon has to have the corner pointing up or down before applying the rotation. Also you can type the calculation directly into the angle field in the Rotate dialog, and Inkscape will make the calculation. If you don't like it feel free to revert. Great answer BTW. +1

Comment: Thanks for the fine edit (like the numerous earlier ones).

Comment: I did it different, I noticed that there is one edge on each 90* rotation. So the one edge between 90* is 45* I divided the 45* by 2 and rotated it by 22.5*. I'm wondering how to add a offset when adding text to the corner nodes